# Define a function to check if its a perfect square in C

Tags: c

I tried to write a code to check if a number is a perfect square, but I'm not able to call the function I defined. Where is my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int isPerfectSquare(int number) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
        if (number == (i * i)) {
            printf("Success");
            break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    printf("Fail");
}

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", n);
    isPerfectSquare(n);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get any answer ("Success" or "Fail").

Comment: `scanf("%d", n);` ==> `scanf("%d", &n);` and watch out for compiler warnings. You should also be getting them because the `int` function isn't returning any value.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks! I've read about by pointers. But I don't see the connection here? Or does & even have anything to do with pointers?

Comment: You must pass the *address* of variable `n` to function `scanf()` and the `&` is the address-of operator. Unlike with `printf()` where you pass the *value* of the variable.

Comment: @WeatherVane I get it! But this means that scanf() will always require the address of a variable n, right? The reason I'm asking is, that we didn't cover pointers yet, but I don't see a possibility of asking a userinput without the pointer.

Comment: Your algorithm is too slow, aside from the issue with the incorrect scanf usage.

Comment: Well, sometimes what you pass to `scanf()` is *already* a pointer, or is implicitly converted to a pointer, but a textbook will probably explain it better. In this case, you have to pass the address of the variable, since `scanf()` needs to be able to change its value.

Comment: Your code always prints "Fail", even when it succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the address of `n` instead of its value in `scanf("%d", n);`:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Note however that your function will print both `Success` and `Fail` for perfect squares because you should return from the function instead of just breaking from the loop upon success.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void isPerfectSquare(int number) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
        if (number == (i * i)) {
            printf("Success\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Fail\n");
}

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        isPerfectSquare(n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that your method is quite slow and may have undefined behavior (and produce false positives) if `i` becomes so large that `i * i` exceeds the range of type `int`.  You should instead use a faster method to figure an approximation of the square root of `n` and check if the result is exact.

It is also better for functions such as `isPerfectSquare()` to return a boolean value instead of printing some message, and let the caller print the message. Here is a modified version using the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method), also known as Heron's method.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isPerfectSquare(int number) {
    int s1 = 2;
    if (number < 0)
        return 0;
    // use the Babylonian method with 10 iterations
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s2 = (s1 + number / s1) / 2;
        if (s1 == s2)
            break;
        s1 = s2;
    }
    return s1 * s1 == number;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        if (isPerfectSquare(n)) {
            printf("Success\n");
        } else {
            printf("Fail\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! I have a few questions:

- Is it correct, that "break" is just used to exit a loop while "return" would terminate the whole function?
- the statement if(scanf("%d", &n)==1) is used to check if the input from the user is an integer. Is that correct?
- In the last version of isPerfectSquare I'm a bit confused. In the part where you define the function you actually never used the "i" you defined in the for-loop and neither the n. Should "n" be replaced by the i in the first line and in the second one "n" will be replaced by "number". Is that right?

Comment: @MyGanton: `break;` can be used to exit from the loop, while `return` exits the function. Some coding conventions disallow either or both, but depending on circumstances, one of these makes the code simple and efficient. The last version of `isPerfectSquare` was bogus: `n` should have been `number`. `i` in only used in the `for` loop logic to make it run at most 10 times. I amended the code to make this more explicit.